# App crashes on Logout Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

So I was following Belal Khan's tutorial on how to make a simple login system for my app.
I followed the tutorial and it works beautifully until the point where I want to logout
I will post down the code for the login VC and the ProfileVC where the logout button exists

Login VC:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
class ViewController: UIViewController {

//The login script url make sure to write the ip instead of localhost
//you can get the ip using ifconfig command in terminal
let URL_USER_LOGIN = "http://madrasati.site/userReg/v1/login.php"

//the defaultvalues to store user data
//the defaultvalues to store user data
let defaultValues = UserDefaults.standard

//the connected views
//don't copy instead connect the views using assistant editor
@IBOutlet weak var labelMessage: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldUserName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldPassword: UITextField!

//the button action function
@IBAction func buttonLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {

    //getting the username and password
    let parameters: Parameters=[
        "username":textFieldUserName.text!,
        "password":textFieldPassword.text!
    ]

    //making a post request
    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_LOGIN, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON
        {
            response in
            //printing response
            print(response)

            //getting the json value from the server
            if let result = response.result.value {
                let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary

                //if there is no error
                if(!(jsonData.value(forKey: "error") as! Bool)){

                    //getting the user from response
                    let user = jsonData.value(forKey: "user") as! NSDictionary

                    //getting user values
                    let userId = user.value(forKey: "id") as! Int
                    let userName = user.value(forKey: "username") as! String
                    let userEmail = user.value(forKey: "email") as! String
                    let userPhone = user.value(forKey: "phone") as! String

                    //saving user values to defaults
                    self.defaultValues.set(userId, forKey: "userid")
                    self.defaultValues.set(userName, forKey: "username")
                    self.defaultValues.set(userEmail, forKey: "useremail")
                    self.defaultValues.set(userPhone, forKey: "userphone")

                    //switching the screen
                    let profileViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)

                    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                }else{
                    //error message in case of invalid credential
                    self.labelMessage.text = "Invalid username or password"
                }
            }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //hiding the navigation button
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: navigationController, action: nil)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //if user is already logged in switching to profile screen
    if defaultValues.string(forKey: "username") != nil{
        let profileViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewcontroller") as! ProfileViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)

    }
}
}
```

ProfileViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

    //label again don't copy instead connect
    @IBOutlet weak var labelUserName: UILabel!

    //button
    @IBAction func buttonLogout(_ sender: UIButton) {

        //removing values from default
        UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        //switching to login screen
        let loginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginViewController, animated: true)
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //hiding back button
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: navigationController, action: nil)
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

        //getting user data from defaults
        let defaultValues = UserDefaults.standard
        if let name = defaultValues.string(forKey: "username"){
            //setting the name to label
            labelUserName.text = name
        }else{
            //send back to login view controller
        }

    }
 }
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
2017-11-30 22:03:33.987292+0400 registerationtest[40711:1152571] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'ViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e981ab __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010552df41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   UIKit                               0x0000000106c2b1f3 -[UIStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController] + 0
    3   registerationtest                   0x0000000104a64221 _T017registerationtest21ProfileViewControllerC12buttonLogoutySo8UIButtonCF + 913
    4   registerationtest                   0x0000000104a6482c _T017registerationtest21ProfileViewControllerC12buttonLogoutySo8UIButtonCFTo + 60
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000106315275 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001064924a2 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001064927bf -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001064916ec -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010638abbb -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2807
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010638c2de -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4124
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010632fe36 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000106c72434 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2809
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000106c75089 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5957
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e3b231 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105edae41 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e1fb49 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e1f12f __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105e1e9b9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010e1809c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    20  UIKit                               0x00000001063135e8 UIApplicationMain + 159
    21  registerationtest                   0x0000000104a63827 main + 55
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a3bed81 start + 1
    23  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

EDIT: 
After assigning a storyboard ID, i'm still getting an error:

```
2017-11-30 22:05:22.424198+0400 registerationtest[40745:1154215] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard () doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'ViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cb6d1ab __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c202f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   UIKit                               0x000000010d9001f3 -[UIStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController] + 0
    3   registerationtest                   0x000000010b739221 _T017registerationtest21ProfileViewControllerC12buttonLogoutySo8UIButtonCF + 913
    4   registerationtest                   0x000000010b73982c _T017registerationtest21ProfileViewControllerC12buttonLogoutySo8UIButtonCFTo + 60
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010cfea275 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010d1674a2 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010d1677bf -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010d1666ec -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010d05fbbb -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2807
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d0612de -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4124
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010d004e36 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010d947434 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2809
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010d94a089 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5957
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cb10231 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cbafe41 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010caf4b49 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010caf412f __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010caf39b9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000114dca9c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010cfe85e8 UIApplicationMain + 159
    21  registerationtest                   0x000000010b738827 main + 55
    22  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111001d81 start + 1
    23  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is referring to this line:

```
let loginViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
```

It is telling you that you haven't assigned the identifier "ViewController" to any UIViewController in your storyboard.  Go to your storyboard, click on the UIViewController, click the Identity Inspector in the panel on the right, and fill in the Storyboard ID field with "ViewController".

[image]

Comment: I didn't notice that, but now i've given it an ID and it's still giving me an error

Comment: Are the 2 viewControllers in the same storyboard?

Comment: nvm it works now thanks very much. the problem was that my Xcode was bugged and it wasn't building properly, not all is good. Thanks a lot!